# How to programmatically add list of web-pages to browser favourites on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, bookmarks

I currently have a list of useful webpages that I am adding to my web-page. I would like to add a link next to each URL that will add it as a bookmark in the users browser. How can I do this?

Further to this, how can I add a "Bookmark all links" button to my page ?

Comment: Anthing you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bookmark on click using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828965/bookmark-on-click-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookmarking for the user isn't supported by some major browsers. You might want to just let the users do it themselves. If you insist, however, this post has some code [Bookmark on click using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828965/bookmark-on-click-using-jquery)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.jQueryBookmark").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the anchor tag from going the user off to the link
    var bookmarkUrl = this.href;
    var bookmarkTitle = this.title;

    if (window.sidebar) { // For Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(bookmarkTitle, bookmarkUrl,"");
    } else if(( window.external && window.external.AddFavorite) || document.all) { // For IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite( bookmarkUrl, bookmarkTitle);
    } else if(window.opera) { // For Opera Browsers
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("href",bookmarkUrl);
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("title",bookmarkTitle);
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("rel","sidebar");
    } else { // for other browsers which does not support
         alert('Your browser does not support this bookmark action');
         return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

This Code is taken from Developersnippets!

Chrome does not support such actions, since the security level could be broken.

Comment: When you found another question where the question is answered, please flag the question as duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: It's a stack overflow link, but I'll add it in.